# Can I force/request windows preemptively cache files to RAM?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, performance, cache

I'm working with some computers with an unusual configuration, where they have mostly high-end components (including a 12th gen i9 CPU and 64GB of DDR5 RAM), but we're booting Windows 10 from old 250GB 5400RPM spinning disks, and are not permitted to upgrade those (it's an educational environment, every student is given one of the disks to work with).

Obviously, the Disk I/O is a major bottleneck to the system as a whole, so I was wondering if there's any good way to request that windows spend any idle time when the disk is inactive caching files to RAM, preferably in a logical order based on how likely they are to be accessed (like to cache the core OS first, before caching all applications). I know the system is caching files as we use them, but it's not practical to manually run every application just to encourage the system to cache them.

As currently configured, the entire system installation should fit in RAM with plenty of space to spare, which would result in a much more responsive system after it had been allowed to idle for long enough to get everything cached into RAM.

Comment: Even in an educational environment, how is it that you were able to upgrade the rest of the computer but not obtain a box of 250GB QLC SSDs? (I mean, the whole box for all your students probably costs less than a single PC.) I'm more familiar with the opposite situation, where we're still trying to get rid of the last Core2Duos...

Answer (score 2):

This feature already exists in Windows in some form.

The feature is called "Superfetch" and is implemented as a
Windows service called "SysMain" which runs in the background
and analyzes your PC usage.

Based on your usage, it determines what apps you're most
likely to use and preloads them into RAM so they can be opened
quickly, which includes preloading all their dependencies.
It may use up to the entire available RAM, but this memory stays
available for allocation if needed.

You may verify that it's running by opening *Start > Services* and
scrolling down to SysMain. Verify that its Status is Running
and that its Startup Type is Automatic, and enable it if not running.

I remark that asking to read the entire HDD into RAM will just thrash
your disk and make Windows unusable while heavily doing I/O for long
minutes. The effects will be negative rather than helpful.